# How to make Header Categories a Different Color on the Home Page Only

Tags: wordpress

My header is separate from my "front-page" and it is pulled to each page using the `get_header();` function. This means that the header will be the same on all pages, **however**, I want to change the font color the something different on the front-page. How can I achieve this result within WordPress?

```
<head>
  <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<section class="navbar custom-navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Website <span></span></a>
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand-short">WBS <span></span></a>
    </div>

    <!-- MENU LINKS -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-nav-first">
        <li><a href="#" class="smoothScroll">Product</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Benefits <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Cat 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cat 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cat 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cat 4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Collection <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Dropdown 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dropdown 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dropdown 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown 6<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Dropdown 4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Dropdown 5</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="">About<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Dropdown 6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dropdown 7</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your menu to a WordPress menu by entering it in admin area under Appearance > Menus.

Then display the menu in your template using the `wp_nav_menu()` function: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/

WordPress will output your menu with classes that allow you to style the links based on which page you are on, which is active etc.

Comment: That Doc page lists out all the classes, here is a link to that part of the page: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/#all-menu-items . The current view link will always get this class `.current-menu-item`.